# QGIS 3 field calculator

Tags: qgis, field-calculator

first: my screenshot

[image]

What I want: the two fields here only with "Straße:" **should be empty**.
The other four results are ok.
What I have done is:

```
CASE WHEN  "Straße/Nr."  IS NOT NULL THEN   ('Straße: '  +  "Straße/Nr.") END
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like the Straße/Nr value for the last two lines in the table is an empty string (`''`), rather than NULL. If they were NULL, it would usually say NULL in pale or gray lettering.

You can account for this by replacing the `"Straße/Nr." is not null` part of your expression with `length("Straße/Nr.")>0`. Or simply add `and "Straße/Nr." is not ''`. Either of the following should work:

```
CASE WHEN length("Straße/Nr.")>0 THEN ('Straße: ' + "Straße/Nr.") END
```

or

```
CASE WHEN "Straße/Nr." IS NOT NULL AND "Straße/Nr." is not '' THEN ('Straße: ' + "Straße/Nr.") END
```

On the other hand, it's possible that some of the Straße/Nr. values are actually strings with whitespace in them (eg, `'  '`). In that case, use the `trim` function to remove starting and ending whitespace, like this:

```
CASE WHEN length(trim("Straße/Nr."))>0 THEN ('Straße: ' + "Straße/Nr.") END
```

Comment: Hello csk,

CASE WHEN length(trim("Straße/Nr."))>0 THEN ('Straße: ' + "Straße/Nr.") END

This is the solution! (The two other ideas do not change my result)

Thank you very much for solution and very quickly answer!

Comment: In that case it might be a good idea to clean up your data by using the Field Calculator to update the Straße/Nr. field with the expression `trim("Straße/Nr.")`. That will permanently remove any values that are just spaces, converting them into empty strings. It will also remove any extra spaces at the start or end of Straße/Nr. values, eg if you had `'Ackerstraße 86 '` it would convert it to `'Ackerstraße 86'`.

Comment: Yes. Perfect!
I used the trim command. After that I can successfully use your solutions above.
Question:
Could you tell me tutorials/websites for this commands, it should be easy for beginners and I need examples.....
Thank you

Comment: Hmm. 
I have a follow question to my case:
Unfortunately I have no success with other fields, before edited with the trim order.
The difference is:
The field "Straße/Nr." I have edited before with a string function command to union Straße and Nr ("Straße"+ ' ' +"Hausnummer"). But the other columns I used only the trim order. But in the result I see again "Straße:"- but the result should be also empty fields, if these columns have no value.
Any idea?

Comment: edit: all Ok. I have had a mistake in my code.....

Comment: The best information about the Field Calculator functions is actually the built-in help section in the Field Calculator. Just click on each function and read the help that pops up on the right. It explains what the function does, what the proper syntax is, and has several examples. Some of that information is in the User Manual, but there's actually more detail in the built-in help.